# Setting timeouts for find in Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have HTML like this

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>...</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input>...</input>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a>  ...</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You get the picture.  Several (in this case 3) rows, each row having tds (67 in this case) and only SOME of the tds having subelements.

I need to go row-by-row and look at each td.  If there is no sub element, then I get the text from the td.  If there is and it is input then if there is only 1 input I get its value.  If two inputs I get the value where type="hidden".

I find my rows with

```
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("blahblahblah//tr");
```

I go through each row and find the tds like

```
 row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
```

This is no problem.  But then I go through the tds to find elements:

```
 td.findElements(By.xpath("*"))
```

(please note this is OK as it is not //*)
So if the td has subelements it comes back right away.  But if not, it waits and waits until timeout.

I did a

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and even a

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Neither worked, as I expect in works only for

```
 driver.findelements(By.xpath)).
```

So is there a way to set this timeout for element finds?  These tds have no ids 
or anything or I could just do a

```
 driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath with id + "//*"));
```

and the timeout would probably work.

Is there any way with an element to get a specific xpath if it has no id or name or blah blah blah?

So two questions: 1: How do you set element timeout, 2: if you have an element how can you get an xpath for it

Comment: No need of the timeout (unless the table loads the data dynamically), please find my answer with dirty code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason for timeout. Just you have to iterate through all the rows and get the data. Here is the dirty code that I have written.

```
    String value;
    int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr")).size();
    int columns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[1]/td")).size();
    for(int row = 1; row <rows+1; ++row) {
        for (int col =1; col<columns+1; col++) {
            //now check if there are any children with input hidden
            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr["+ row +"]/td["+ col +"]/input[@type='hidden']")).size()>0) {
                value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr["+ row +"]/td["+ col +"]/input[@type='hidden']")).getAttribute("value");
            }
            //now check if there are any children with input without hidden
            else if ((driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr["+ row +"]/td["+ col +"]/input")).size()>0)) {
                value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr["+ row +"]/td["+ col +"]/input")).getAttribute("value"); 

            }
            //just get text as there are no children input
            else {
                value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr["+ row +"]/td["+ col +"]")).getText();
            }
            System.out.println("Row:" + row + " Col:" + col + " value:" + value);
            }
    }
```